# (Bloomberg) BDP Formula question

Tags: bloomberg, excel

Good Morning,

I am using the below formula and need some help, how do I change the below strike price (400) to pull from a separate cell (T2) I have on the spreadsheet?

```
=BDP("odcn8c_*400*_comdty","vega")*I68*50
```

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate the string (and replace the `_` with spaces to form a valid ticker):

```
=BDP("odcn8c " & T2 & " Comdty", "vega") * I68 * 50
```

Comment: After trying this I am getting the following, "#N/A Invalid"

Comment: with `400` in cell `T2` it works for me, unless you have something incorrect in cell I68.

Comment: the value in `I68` i don't think would be able to cause an `#N/A Invalid` result, as that's what bbg returns.

Comment: Make sure you have 400 as a string, not as a number. Use text conversion if necessary, example: =TEXT(I68)

Comment: @Dominic So `=BDP("odcn8c 200 Comdty", "vega")` works, but `=BDP("odcn8c " & T2 & " Comdty", "vega")` with `200` in `T2` doesn't?